# bash shell script: Zip folder and all the content under not any directories above

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Im trying to zip the folder and all of its contents with in it. Everytime i execute it it includes folders above the username such as Users Desktop and USERNAME

```
 zip -r ~/Desktop/ZIP_THIS_FOLDER.zip ~/Desktop/ZIP_THIS_FOLDER
```

**ZIP_THIS_FOLDER.ZIP CONTENT**

USERS -> USERNAME -> Desktop -> ZIP_THIS_FOLDER -> FOLDERA -> FOLDERB -> .... etc.

needs to be:

**ZIP_THIS_FOLDER.ZIP CONTENT**

ZIP_THIS_FOLDER -> FOLDERA -> FOLDERB -> .... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change working directory to folder which contains `ZIP_THIS_FOLDER` first

```
cd ~/Desktop
zip -r ZIP_THIS_FOLDER ZIP_THIS_FOLDER
```